# is there any project which has set of classes in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, frameworks

I am new to .net and was wondering if there are any projects which have sets of vb.net classes online which i can use. For example we have Flourish — PHP Unframework  which has lots of php classes therefore a programmer doesn't not to replicate code on each project. Is there a asp.net (vb) resource website or any open source project which has built in vb.net functions.

Comment: That "project" is called [Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)  ;)

Comment: I thought .net was the framework on top of the language (VB, ASP, C#) that provides you with the common abstractions that you would find in other frameworks/libraries (akin to what cocoa is to objective-c), that said I have never really had the inclination to use or learn .net so...

Comment: @Tom: The framework's [base class library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library) is not an abstraction but an implementation of all assemblies,namespaces,types(classes) and members. I guess .NET 4.0 has more than 12000 types currently. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2008/03/17/number-of-types-in-the-net-framework.aspx Edit: Maybe a lot more(44,346): http://www.ginktage.com/2010/07/interesting-statistics-on-net-framework-4-0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a lot here:

http://clrextensions.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are common bits that many groups use.. check out the [MS Patterns and Practices site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/bb190332) as well as [NuGet](http://nuget.org/)

Answer (score 0):

.Net is a framework; therefore, built into it are myriad types. I would recommend creating a project (File:New Project in Visual Studio) and play with the Object Browser.

To do this (for example), open Solution Explorer, expand the References folder for your project, and double-click `System`. This is the core of the framework, and you can expand out namespaces and look at classes to your heart's content.